# Load contents from a CSV file into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, bulkinsert, database-partitioning, psql

Below is a description of the procedure I went through to try and load data from a file into a PostgreSQL 8.0 database running on a Linux RedHat 7.2 host.

Now, my issue is that the `FOR EVERY ROW` trigger is getting called and the procedure is executing.

What I'd like it to do, however, is have it check the appropriate row of my table once I have given in the filename and decide based on the contents of the record whether to do a `DUMP BULK DATA` or a `DUMP WHOLE CSV FILE` only once (on the trigger).

Please help me solve this issue...

My `logfile.tmp` is as follows:

```
27/Apr/2013:17:03:42 +0530#192.168.1.3#16#0@#$http://localhost/images/
   banner-left.jpg@#$10.1ff.ff.ff#-#Y#-
27/Apr/2013:17:03:42 +0530#192.168.1.3#16#0@#$http://localhost/images/
   banner-left.jpg@#$10.ff.ff.2ff05#-#Y#-
```

The COPY command I am using:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql localhost -d d1 -U u1 -tc "COPY tblaccesslog ( accesstime, clientip, username, request,bytes, urlpath, url, contenttype, issite, webcatname)  FROM 'logfile.tmp' WITH DELIMITER AS '#';" >> /tmp/parselog.log 2>&1
```

The trigger (`insert_accesslog_trigger`) in question:

```
insert_accesslog_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON tblaccesslog FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE accesslog_insert_trigger()
```

and finally the trigger function (`accesslog_insert_trigger()`) being used:

```
accesslog_insert_trigger()
DECLARE
        tablemaxtuples NUMERIC(10);
        tableno NUMERIC(10);
        newtable TEXT;
        query TEXT;
        tablecount NUMERIC(10);
        min_limit NUMERIC(10);
        max_limit NUMERIC(10);
BEGIN

        tablemaxtuples := 100000;
    tableno := ( NEW.id - ( NEW.id % tablemaxtuples ) ) / tablemaxtuples +1;
    newtable := 'tblaccesslog'||to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')||'_child_'||tableno;

        SELECT trim(count(tablename)) INTO tablecount FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename=newtable ;
    IF tablecount = 0
    THEN
                min_limit := (tableno-1)*tablemaxtuples;
                max_limit := min_limit + tablemaxtuples;
                                query := 'CREATE TABLE '||newtable||'( PRIMARY KEY (id),CHECK ( id >= '||min_limit||' AND id <'||max_limit||'  ) ) INHERITS (tblaccesslog)';
        EXECUTE query;
     END IF;

    query := 'INSERT INTO '|| newtable ||' ( id, username, clientip, url, accesstime, requestbytes, contenttype, issite, urlpath, webcatname ) VALUES ('||NEW.id||','''||NEW.username||''','''||NEW.clientip||''','''||NEW.url||''','''||NEW.accesstime||''','''||NEW.requestbytes||''','''||NEW.contenttype||''','''||NEW.issite||''','''|| replace(NEW.urlpath,'\'','') ||''','''||NEW.webcatname||''')';
    EXECUTE query;
    RETURN NULL;

END;
```

Comment: 8.0 is very old, and probably has unpatched security issues.  Please upgrade as soon as you can.

Comment: Red Hat 7.2 is even older (2001) with possibly more security issues. You should migrate this data to a modern server ASAP.

Comment: I can't upgrade anyone of them.. Because of some reasons..Can you help me with this configuration only ?

Answer (score 2):

The [PostgreSQL documentation overview of triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html) makes clear that there is no type of trigger that suits your requirements: a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger will, as its name says, be executed once for each row, and as the manual page states "Statement-level triggers do not currently have any way to examine the individual row(s) modified by the statement."

However, what you can do instead is put your actual `COPY` command inside a function. The function could `COPY TO` a temporary table and then perform the appropriate steps to determine where it should go from there.

Then your copy command (which I'm guessing is in a `cron` job or similar) would just run `SELECT bulk_insert_access_log();` rather than the long line currently listed.

Comment: Here My problem is with this setup Its taking too much CPU consumption  for every call of trigger. So I just want to decrease it. with only call trigger  when the CRON calls new file to be dump. So temp database will not solve my problem.

Comment: Triggers can be defined to execute either before or after any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation, either once per modified row, or once "per SQL statement".  in this statement it shows I can call trigger with SQL call... so How to achieve it ? what changes I suppose to make ?

Comment: If you use a trigger which runs for the whole statement, you do not have access to the data which was inserted, as I quoted already. But there is no reason this *has* to be a trigger at all -  just write a custom function and run it from cron.

Comment: Ya I think its better way.. Is there any way in PSQL that I can know which was the lastly updated table ? and In which table I suppose to add next upcoming data ?

Comment: You could keep track of the last table used in another table perhaps - something like `select max(partition_no) + 1 from partitioned_table_info`...